# List of tuples with a certain pattern

Tags: python, list, tuples

Is there a way to create a list of tuples with a certain pattern?
I want to have the following list without having to manually write them all, I think it may be "easy" since there is kind of a pattern in the tuple list, but not sure how to do it.

```
a = [
[(30, 5, 10),
(30, 5, 20),
(30, 5, 30),
(30, 10, 10),
(30, 10, 20),
(30, 10, 30),
(30, 20, 10),
(30, 20, 20),
(30, 20, 30)],

[(35, 5, 10),
(35, 5, 20),
(35, 5, 30),
(35, 10, 10),
(35, 10, 20),
(35, 10, 30),
(35, 20, 10),
(35, 20, 20),
(35, 20, 30)],

[(40, 5, 10),
(40, 5, 20),
(40, 5, 30),
(40, 10, 10),
(40, 10, 20),
(40, 10, 30),
(40, 20, 10),
(40, 20, 20),
(40, 20, 30)]
    ]
a
```

Output:

```
[[(30, 5, 10),
  (30, 5, 20),
  (30, 5, 30),
  (30, 10, 10),
  (30, 10, 20),
  (30, 10, 30),
  (30, 20, 10),
  (30, 20, 20),
  (30, 20, 30)],
 [(35, 5, 10),
  (35, 5, 20),
  (35, 5, 30),
  (35, 10, 10),
  (35, 10, 20),
  (35, 10, 30),
  (35, 20, 10),
  (35, 20, 20),
  (35, 20, 30)],
 [(40, 5, 10),
  (40, 5, 20),
  (40, 5, 30),
  (40, 10, 10),
  (40, 10, 20),
  (40, 10, 30),
  (40, 20, 10),
  (40, 20, 20),
  (40, 20, 30)]]
```

Comment: can you show us the code you tried? we can help you in fixing it and suggest you better approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this list comprehensions:

```
l1 =[30,35,40]
l2 =[5,10,20]
l3= [10,20,30] 

l =  [[(i1,i2,i3) for i2 in l2 for i3 in l3 ]for i1 in l1]
```

If you want to add number just add it to the inner tuple (for exmaple, 10):

```
l =  [[(10,i1,i2,i3) for i2 in l2 for i3 in l3 ]for i1 in l1]
```

Comment: This seems to work exactly as intended, is there a way to add another constant with list comprehensions (at the begging or end)? for example add to all tuples a 10 at `[0] `

Comment: Sure, the given solution correctly shows: `(30, 5, 10), (30, 5, 20), (30, 5, 30)...` is there a way to add a variable to all tuples? Say `(x, 30, 5, 10), (x, 30, 5, 20), (x, 30, 5, 30)...`
In the previous comment I said 10 just to say something, but it could be any number

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using the [range function](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp), with step.

> range(start, stop, step)

A simple way of doing this is like this:

```
array = []

for x in range(30, 45, 5):
    y_tuple_multipler = 1
    sub_array = []
    for y in range(1, 4):
        y_tuple = 5 * y_tuple_multipler
        for z in range(10, 40, 10):
            sub_array.append((x, y_tuple, z))
        y_tuple_multipler *= 2
    array.append(sub_array)
print(array)
```

You can probably get more `pythonic`, but simplicity is always good (and easier to debug multiple loops)

Comment: @adirabargil how so? I did a print and it's an exact output from what the OP wants

Comment: The second range is not iterating 5,10,20 it iterates 5,10,15,20...

Comment: Indeed, it iterates `5, 10, 15, 20` instead of `5, 10, 20` that was kind of the problem I was having.

Comment: @DanielRodríguez does that give you what you're looking for? You're going to have to tweak your loops based on your need and the math required to get the iterations you want